# Realloc int array's new spaces in memory to 0

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, realloc

I have an int array that needs to grow when it sees a higher int value than it already has, is there any way to call realloc() and set all the new spaces in memory that are being created? Or do I need to loop through all the new spaces in memory and set them to 0 one by one? Code below for clarity.

```
int main(){
    int i;
    int currentSize = 10;
    int *checkList = malloc(sizeof(int) * currentSize);
    while((i = readInt(fp))){
        if(i > currentSize){
             currentSize = i + 1;
             checklist = realloc(checkList, sizeof(int) * (i + 1));
             //Need to loop through checklist and declare empty mem to 0?
        } 
        if(!checkList[i]) checkList[i]++;
    }

    //should have an array where seen values index in checklist == 1
}
```

Comment: Neither [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) nor [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) initializes the memory it allocates. If you want it initialized in any way you need to either call [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) or do it yourself with [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset).

Comment: So I will need to allocate a new array, set all those to 0 and then copy over the values item by item to the new array

Comment: No, just initialise the new elements.

Comment: `if(i > currentSize)` should be `if(i >= currentSize)` because (for example) if `i` is 10, that is beyond the initial range allocated.

Comment: Suggest start with `int currentSize = 0; int *checkList = NULL;`

Comment: BTW, consider what happens if `readInt()` returns a negative number.

Comment: This is not the actual code, just the code to get a point across :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is how you could do the `realloc`ation - it expands it to `newSize` and then uses `memset` to set the new elements to 0.

```
if(i >= currentSize) {
     int newSize = i + 1;
     checkList = realloc(checkList, sizeof(int) * newSize);
     memset(checkList+currentSize,0,sizeof(int) * (newSize - currentSize));
     currentSize = newSize;
}
```

You'd probably want to use `memset` or `calloc` on your initial allocation to make sure those values are also 0 BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping, you can use `memset` to set all values in a particular memory range to a intended value.

You code can be modified like below to use memset

```
int main(){
    int i;
    int currentSize = 10;
    int *checkList = malloc(sizeof(int) * currentSize);
    while((i = readInt(fp))){
        if(i >= currentSize){
             checklist = realloc(checkList, sizeof(int) * (i + 1));
             //Need to loop through checklist and declare empty mem to 0?
             memset(checklist+currentSize, 0, (sizeof(int) * ((i+1) - currentSize)));
             currentSize = i + 1;
        } 
        if(!checkList[i]) checkList[i]++;
    }

    //should have an array where seen values index in checklist == 1
}
```

Comment: So I could use `realloc` then `memset` on the range that's outside of the original array?

Comment: realloc will give you contiguous memory. You can memset that part of memory which is already unassigned using memset.

Comment: @chux - Done! : )